# How difficult is it to travel with a yumi (longbow) in Japan?

Tags: japan, japan-rail

I'm planning a trip to Japan end of next march. I want to take my yumi (Japanese longbow, around 2.3 meters long) with me, as I have some contacts I'd like to train with.

Now I was wondering how difficult it is to travel with such a long piece of luggage in Japan, specifically on trains (Shinkansen).

I have found this [notice here](http://www.jreast.co.jp/kippu/20.html):

> 〈持ち込める荷物〉
>
> ●携帯できる荷物で、タテ・ヨコ・高さの合計が250センチ（長さは2メートルまで）以内で、重さが30キロ以内のものを2個まで持ち込むことができます。

Which means (if I'm not mistaken): Width + height + length < 250 cm. And neither one of them larger than 2 m. And under 30 kg (not a problem here).

Which would mean, I cannot take a yumi on a Shinkansen.

What are my options? Just take it with me and explain that it is a yumi (hoping for understanding) or use a shipping service between the places where I stay (or where I want to use it, if storing for a few days is possible)?

Comment: Yes I'll probably ask my contacts as well.

Comment: Is renting a car not an option?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I plan on going there for 3 weeks, and want to go from Tokyo to Miyakonojo and then to Sapporo (some stops between), so I don't think that renting a car is a nice approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of rules for what you're can and can't bring on trains, but in my experience **enforcement is very lax** if you're not being an obvious nuisance — there are no conductors with tape measures inspecting every piece of luggage that comes in.  So while your mileage may vary, I suspect you'll be just fine even though your *yumi* is 2.3m instead of 2.0m.

Here's a [random forum thread](https://www.cosp.jp/chie_question.aspx?id=21) (in Japanese) discussing bringing various awkward objects including a 2m-long sword (!) on Japanese trains and buses, and nobody reported any problems.

Answer (score 3):

You should have no trouble at all with a Yumi (longbow) on the trains in Japan. I see people carrying them all the time. I wouldn't worry about it.